# How to fix Evicted Modules issue in Apache Ivy

Tags: java, ant, ivy

I'm trying to integrate Apache Ivy with an existing Java EE project which uses Apache Ant. I created ivy.xml, ivysettings.xml(to add an non-existent repo in mvnrepo) and made changes to the existing build.xml.

I got the following when I ran the Ivy Resolve:

```
[ivy:resolve] :: resolution report :: resolve 2642ms :: artifacts dl 49ms
[ivy:resolve]   :: evicted modules:
[ivy:resolve]   xml-apis#xml-apis;1.0.b2 by [xml-apis#xml-apis;1.3.04] in [default]
[ivy:resolve]   commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1 by [commons-logging#commons-logging;1.2] in [default]
[ivy:resolve]   commons-codec#commons-codec;1.6 by [commons-codec#commons-codec;1.8] in [default]
[ivy:resolve]   commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.3 by [commons-logging#commons-logging;1.2] in [default]
[ivy:resolve]   org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.1 by [org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.7] in [default]
[ivy:resolve]   xml-apis#xml-apis;1.3.04 by [xml-apis#xml-apis;1.4.01] in [default]
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      default     |  108  |   0   |   0   |   6   ||  102  |   0   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I fix this issue? These modules are not directly mentioned in the ivy.xml. This is my first experiment with Ivy and any help would be highly appreciated.

### ivysettings.xml

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="central"/>
    <resolvers>
        <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true"/>
        <ibiblio name="primefaces-themes-old" m2compatible="true" root="http://repository.primefaces.org"/>
    </resolvers>
    <modules>
        <module organisation="org.primefaces.themes" resolver="primefaces-themes-old"/>
    </modules>
</ivysettings>
```

### ivy.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">
    <info organisation="Fetching Life" module="WebApp" status="integration">
    </info>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="commons-collections" name="commons-collections" rev="3.2.2" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="mysql" name="mysql-connector-java" rev="5.1.40" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="com.googlecode.flyway" name="flyway-core" rev="2.3.1" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="com.googlecode.flyway" name="flyway-ant" rev="2.3.1" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-core" rev="5.0.11.Final" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-core" rev="4.2.8.RELEASE" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-web" rev="4.2.8.RELEASE" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-orm" rev="4.2.8.RELEASE" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-context" rev="4.2.8.RELEASE" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-context-support" rev="4.2.8.RELEASE" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-test" rev="4.2.8.RELEASE" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-oxm" rev="4.2.8.RELEASE" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-webmvc" rev="4.2.8.RELEASE" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-webmvc-portlet" rev="4.2.8.RELEASE" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-aspects" rev="4.2.8.RELEASE" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="org.primefaces" name="primefaces" rev="5.1" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="com.sun.faces" name="jsf-api" rev="2.1.29" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="com.sun.faces" name="jsf-impl" rev="2.1.29" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="joda-time" name="joda-time" rev="2.8.2" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="org.apache.shiro" name="shiro-all" rev="1.2.6" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="com.google.apis" name="google-api-services-calendar" rev="v3-rev179-1.19.1" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="com.google.code.gson" name="gson" rev="2.3.1" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="org.mnode.ical4j" name="ical4j" rev="1.0.7" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="net.sourceforge.jexcelapi" name="jxl" rev="2.6.12" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="javax.el" name="javax.el-api" rev="2.2.5" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="com.ocpsoft" name="prettyfaces-jsf2" rev="3.3.3" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="org.mindrot" name="jbcrypt" rev="0.3m" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="javax.jdo" name="jdo-api" rev="3.0.1" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="org.quartz-scheduler" name="quartz" rev="2.2.3" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="org.omnifaces" name="omnifaces" rev="1.6.3" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="javax.servlet.jsp.jstl" name="jstl-api" rev="1.2" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="antlr" name="antlr" rev="2.7.7" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="org.apache.james" name="apache-mime4j" rev="0.6.1" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="org.atmosphere" name="atmosphere-runtime" rev="2.2.9" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="bsh" name="bsh" rev="1.3.0" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.12" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="org.mockito" name="mockito-all" rev="1.10.19" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="commons-fileupload" name="commons-fileupload" rev="1.2.2" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="org.apache.commons" name="commons-exec" rev="1.3" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="commons-io" name="commons-io" rev="2.4" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="commons-jxpath" name="commons-jxpath" rev="1.3" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="net.sf.ehcache" name="ehcache" rev="2.10.0" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="org.glassfish.web" name="el-impl" rev="2.2" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="net.sf.jsr107cache" name="jsr107cache" rev="1.1" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="javax.mail" name="mail" rev="1.4.7" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="io.netty" name="netty" rev="3.5.13.Final" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="org.objenesis" name="objenesis" rev="2.1" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="com.google.protobuf" name="protobuf-java" rev="2.4.1" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="xalan" name="serializer" rev="2.7.2" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="xalan" name="xalan" rev="2.7.2" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="xerces" name="xercesImpl" rev="2.11.0" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="org.primefaces.themes" name="casablanca" rev="1.0.10" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="net.sourceforge.cssparser" name="cssparser" rev="0.9.20" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="dom4j" name="dom4j" rev="1.6.1" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="org.ini4j" name="ini4j" rev="0.5.4" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="org.eclipse.jetty" name="jetty-websocket" rev="8.1.22.v20160922" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="org.w3c.css" name="sac" rev="1.3" conf="default"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="SampleApp" default="usage" basedir="." xmlns:flyway="antlib:com.googlecode.flyway.ant" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">
<property name="lib.dir" value="${basedir}/${web.dir}/WEB-INF/lib/"></property>
<target name="resolve" description="resolve dependencies with ivy">
        <ivy:resolve conf="default"/>
    </target>

    <target name="cleancache" description="Purge ivy cache">
        <ivy:cleancache/>
    </target>

    <target name="dependencytree" depends="resolve" description="Show dependency tree">
        <ivy:dependencytree />
    </target>

    <target name="retrieve" depends="resolve" description="Resolve and Retrieve with ivy">
        <ivy:retrieve conf="default" sync="true" type="jar,bundle" pattern="${lib.dir}[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
        <!-- <ivy:cachepath pathid="default.classpath" /> -->
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Could you please add the XMLs you mentioned?

Comment: @cantSleepNow I have added the XML to the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add the line `<conflict manager="all"/>` before closing the dependencies tag you won't have any evicted modules. Like so

```
    <conflict manager="all"/>
</dependencies>
```

Quoting from [here](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/trunk/settings/conflict-managers.html) for the built-in conflict manager `all`:

> this conflicts manager resolve conflicts by selecting all revisions.
>   Also called the NoConflictManager, it **doesn't evict any modules.**

I had to put the `conflict` at the end, otherwise it won't work. Seems like [a bug in ivy](http://javamoody.blogspot.co.at/2014/05/ivy.html).

Just be sure that this is what you want. Quoting from [here](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/trunk/ivyfile/conflict.html):

> There are two things optimized during conflict resolution: download of
>   artifacts and download of ivy files. The first is always ensured by
>   ivy, i.e. artifacts of a module evicted will never be downloaded. The
>   second is not as simple to handle because to know what are the
>   conflicts ivy needs to know the dependency graph, and to know the
>   dependency graph, it has to download ivy files. But ivy is highly
>   optimized on this too, and it tries to evict modules as soon as
>   possible. That's why the order of dependencies is important for
>   download optimization. Indeed ivy traverses the dependency graph in
>   the order in which dependencies are declared in the ivy files, and
>   each time it encounters a dependency on a module, it first check if
>   there is a conflict on this module, and if this is the case, it asks
>   the conflict manager to resolve the conflict. Then if the module is
>   evicted, it does not download its ivy file, and the whole branch is
>   not traversed, which can saves a lot of time.

Comment: This worked for me. Earlier, I tried adding conflict to the beginning of the file and it failed with an exception. Actually I need *strict*, but I have some very old libraries so there are couple of conflicts. Thank you very much for the quick response

Comment: Curious to know why do you want to retain all versions of a module for the same project though?

Answer (score 2):

Just to add something.

The conflict section works perfectly.

```
<conflict manager="all"/>
```

Anyway it's not easy to find information about it, and it may be just useful to know that its usage can be limited to a single dependency or and also uses wildcards to select a subset of them. In my case, i'm using it like this:

```
<conflict manager="all" module="module_1" org="org_1"/>
```

Moreover there is also the option to select different strategies using different managers, more info at: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.0.0/settings/conflict-managers.html